# Find possible value of $g(3)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, quadratics

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are quadratic polynomial with positive integral coefficients. Let the values of $f(g(x))$ and $g(f(x))$ at points $x=0$ and $x=1$ be as follows

1)$f(g(0))=\alpha$ and $f(g(1))=31$

And

2)$g(f(0))=5$ and $g(f(1))=\beta$

Then find possible value of $g(3)$

**My try**:

Let $f(x)=x^2+bx+c$ and $g(x)=x^2+dx+e$ for some positive integers $b, c, d, e$.

From given information we get the the following

1)$ f(e)=\alpha$ and $g(c)=5$

And

2)$$g(c)+g(1+b)=\beta -2c-2bc+e$$
$$f(e)+f(1+d)=31-2e-2de+c$$

But I see no way to get $g(3)$ from the information I found.  Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you assume the polynomials monic? Couldn't the leading coefficient be $>1$?

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen Of course they can be but that would in turn make my method very cumbersome so thought to take the monic polynomial and see the trend if any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, $g(x)=dx^2+ex+f$ with $a,b,c,d,e,f$ positive integers.
Then $f(0)=c\ge 1$.
If we had $f(0)\ge 2$, then $5=g(f(0))\ge 4d+2e+f\ge 7$, contradiction. We conclude $$c=1$$ and then $$d+e+f=5.$$
Now we know that $$31=f(g(1))=f(5)=25a+5b+1\ge 25+5+1=31,$$ so that by sharpness of the inequality necessarily $$a=b=1.$$
Meanwhile, we can express $\alpha$ and $\beta$ more nicely:
$$ \alpha=f(g(0))=f^2+f+1,\qquad \beta=g(f(1))=g(3).$$
However, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are of no use anyway.
Instead, $d+e+f=5$ means that the only posisbilities for $(d,e,f)$ are 
$$(1,1,3), (1,2,2), (1,3,1), (2,1,2), (2,2,1), (3,1,1) $$
with the following corresponding values of $g(3)$ (and hence $\beta$):
$$ 15, 17, 19, 23, 25, 31.$$